# Python cycling through indentation

Tags: indentation, python

Cycling through indentation levels in `python.el` [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838448/cycling-through-possible-indentations-in-python-el-in-emacs) can be achieved by pressing `<tab>` repeatedly, which is bound to `indent-for-tab-command`.

Now, consider:

```
(defun malb/my-indent (&optional arg)
    (interactive "P")
    (indent-for-tab-command arg))
(bind-key "C-<tab>" #'malb/my-indent)
```

Now, pressing `C-<tab>` repeatedly does not lead to cycling through indentation levels. On the other hand,

```
(bind-key "C-<tab>" #'indent-for-tab-command)
```

does lead to the desired outcome. Hence, somehow, calling `indent-for-tab-command` from another function behaves differently from calling it directly. Can anyone explain why that is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow through the code of `indent-for-tab-command`, you'll see the indentation is actually done by a `indent-line-function`. In Python mode, this is `python-indent-line-function`. The help for this function indicates that the cycling behaviour is only triggered if the previous command is in the list `python-indent-trigger-commands`. `malb/myindent` isn't in that list of course, so it doesn't work as you want.

You can fix this by adding your function:

```
(add-to-list 'python-indent-trigger-commands 'malb/my-indent)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by Tyler](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21186/93) is correct.  I wanted to point out an alternative (but inferior) way to solve the problem.  If it weren't for the variable `python-indent-trigger-commands` that Tyler pointed out, you might be stuck with finding a way of letting your command `malb/my-indent` masquerade as `intend-for-tab-command`.  One way to achieve that would be as follows:

```
(defun my-indent (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (not (called-interactively-p))
      (indent-for-tab-command arg)
    (setq this-command 'indent-for-tab-command)
    (call-interactively 'indent-for-tab-command)))
```

This allows your wrapper layer to be more of a transparent pass-through.  In your specific case, the use of `call-interactively` is not strictly necessary to achieve the desired effect, but it is in many other cases where you want to provide a wrapper around an existing command.  That is because many commands behave differently depending on whether they were called interactively or called from lisp.